# Can I run angular's digest loop at 60fps to display a fast timer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a timer to display on my website and I'd like the value to be in my angular controller. Currently I use this code:

```
var interval=1.0 / 60.0;
var score_div = $("#score_div");
setInterval(function(){
    score += interval;
    score_div.text(score);
}, interval * 1000);
```

Can angular handle digesting at 60FPS? How else could I have a timer update frequently enough? It's a pretty simple variable, and using jQuery or something I could update the DOM myself during that Interval function.

Is there an "angular" way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you really changing the score 60 times a second? I'm assuming you're making a game, so I'm imagining that would only update every few seconds based on player actions. Pushing updates when they happen would make more sense if that's the case.

Comment: Actually, it's more like a count-down/count-up timer, and I don't want it to be jerky or only update once a second. The actual updating is trivial, I just want to make sure angular can handle it or that there isn't a better way to display an incrementing number at 60fps.

Comment: A WebGL library like pixiJS *might* be faster than DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do DOM manipulation with angular if you don't have to, leave that to angular and just update your model. You can create a controller/directive and use the [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service so that angular knows about changes to your scope variable `score`. Example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
  var interval=1.0 / 60.0;
  $scope.score = 0;
  $interval(function(){
      $scope.score += interval;
  }, interval * 1000);
}]);
```

and your markup would be

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!-- You don't actually need an ID here for it to work -->
    <div id="#score_div">{{score}}</div>
  </body>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9lAqBeySyIYTNyPykgK2?p=preview)

Comment: How well does angular handle digesting that quickly? Will the whole model digest, or just single values? Since I know what the values are going to do, do I really need to let angular figure it out through a complicated digest cycle?

Comment: A digest happens so that angular can update your view to match your entire model or the other way around and call the relevant watchers, not to figure out the new value. So don't bind a model to your scope if you don't need it displayed. If you have hundreds of DOM elements that need to be rendered after a digest, e.g. in an `ng-repeat` then browser will lag or freeze. Otherwise it's pretty good from my experience.

Comment: Well, regardless of what Angular is doing behind the scenes, it's working for me. It seems like overkill but TBH it's so much easier for me this way.